# Checking if a folder exists (and creating folders) in Qt, C++

Tags: c++, qt, filesystems

In Qt, how do I check if a given folder exists in the current directory?
If it doesn't exist, how do I then create an empty folder?

Answer (score 248, accepted):

To check if a directory named "Folder" exists use:

```
QDir("Folder").exists();
```

To create a new folder named "MyFolder" use:

```
QDir().mkdir("MyFolder");
```

Comment: How does this answer compare to @Petrucio's answer? I can't deduce this from the docs.

Comment: Why it isn't static? `QDir::exists("absolutepath")` and `QDir::mkdir(""absolutepath")`

Comment: @yalov - because it would collide with non-static `QDir::mkdir("relative_path")`. Not possible to have both overloads.

Comment: @JonasG.Drange This answer does not create intermediate folders in a complex/path/structure/with/intermediate/folders. My answer is objectively better; the reason it has less upvotes is because it was posted two years after this one.

Answer (score 195):

To both check if it exists and create if it doesn't, including intermediaries:

```
QDir dir("path/to/dir");
if (!dir.exists())
    dir.mkpath(".");
```

Comment: Why pass the `"."` argument in `dir.mkpath(".")`?

Comment: Because "." is the current dir, which we've set as the directory we want to create.

Answer (score 12):

When you use QDir.mkpath() it returns true if the path already exists, in the other hand QDir.mkdir() returns false if the path already exists. So depending on your program you have to choose which fits better.

You can see more on [Qt Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html#mkpath)

Answer (score -14):

Why use anything else?

```
  mkdir(...);
```

Comment: Because you can't use it like that in Qt.

Comment: @Patapoom He probably meant the Linux function.

Comment: Because it's not cross-platform.