# How do I check for an existing folder in qml?

Tags: javascript, mobile, qml, directory

I am programming in qml for a mobile client.  I want to check if a particular folder exists on the mobile device.  If not, I want to create it. I am using qml, so solutions can be in qml or JavaScript.

(Note: when I say "JavaScript", people say "use php,ajax etc." but I can only use JavaScript and qml on my mobile platform)

Comment: You can't do this in a raw QML/js application as there is no filesystem support. Is there an underlying Qt runner or are you using the stock QmlViewer? You can certainly implement this functionality in Qt C++ and then expose it to QML.

Comment: ok, how can i do  it with Qt c++? at least is there any link to start?

Comment: In 2019's labs at least reading file system access is possible: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-folderlistmodel-folderlistmodel.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in Qt (like @Stu-Mackellar already said).

Access Qt methods like this:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qt-maemo-4.7/qtbinding.html#calling-c-methods-from-qml

and do the Qt part like described here:

[Checking if a folder exists (and creating folders) in Qt, C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241808/checking-if-a-folder-exists-and-creating-folders-in-qt-c)