# Why is there no static QDir::makepath()?

Tags: qt, qdir

I know, that to create a new path in Qt from a given absolute path, you use `QDir::makepath()` as `dir.makepath(path)`, as it is suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641807/qdir-mkdir-with-absolutepath) question. I do not have any trouble in using it and it works fine. My question is directed, as to **why** the developers would not provide a static function to call in a way like `QDir::makepath("/Users/me/somepath/");`. Needing to create a new `QDir` instance seems unnecessary to me.

I can only think of two possible reasons:

**1.** The developers were "lazy" or did not have time so they did not add one as it is not absolutely necessary.

**2.** The instance of `QDir` on which `mkpath(path)` is called, will be set to `path` as well, so it would be convenient for further usage - but I can not seem to find any hints that this is the actual behaviour within the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#mkdir).

I know I repeat myself, but again, I do **not** need help as of *how* to do it, but I am much interested as of *why* one has to do it that way.
Thanks for any reason I might have missed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's have a look at the code of said method:

```
bool QDir::mkdir(const QString &dirName) const
{
    const QDirPrivate* d = d_ptr.constData();

    if (dirName.isEmpty()) {
        qWarning("QDir::mkdir: Empty or null file name");
        return false;
    }

    QString fn = filePath(dirName);
    if (d->fileEngine.isNull())
        return QFileSystemEngine::createDirectory(QFileSystemEntry(fn), false);
    return d->fileEngine->mkdir(fn, false);
}
```

*Source: http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/io/qdir.cpp#n1381*

As we can see, a static version would be simple to implement:

```
bool QDir::mkdir(const QString &dirName) const
{
    if (dirName.isEmpty()) {
        qWarning("QDir::mkdir: Empty or null file name");
        return false;
    }

    return QFileSystemEngine::createDirectory(QFileSystemEntry(dirName), false);
}
```

*(see also http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/io/qdir.cpp#n681)*

First, the non-static method comes with a few advantages. Obviously there is something to using the object's existing file engine. But also, I would imagine the use-case of creating several directories under a specific directory (that the `QDir` already points to).

So why not provide both?

**Verdict (tl/dr):** I think the reason is simple code hygiene. When you use the API, the difference between `QDir::makepath(path);` and `QDir().makepath(path);` is slim. The performance hit of creating the object is also negligible, as you would reuse the same object if you happen to perform the operation more often. But on the side of the code maintainers, it is arguably much more convenient (less work and less error prone) to *not* maintain two versions of the same method.

Comment: As I pointed out, and is also given an example with another method in the docs, you can write it in a single line as `QDir().makepath(path);`.