# asking for folder creation in qt

Tags: qt, qt4

How can i ask one user to create a folder through one dialog box in qt .

So that whatever the name the user has given in the dialog box ( in a specific location,

for eg. c:/user/...) the folder will be created in that location and if the folder is

alreday present with the specific name in that location  then replacement shall be done .

Comment: Did you try to write anything? Where do you have problem?

Comment: Please take a look at other questions here first. This looks like it should answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241808/checking-if-a-folder-exists-and-creating-folders-in-qt-c

Comment: Please refer to the QDir Class Reference http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdir.html#setPath. It appears that what you need is QDir::setPath() and QDir::mkdir(). Also, Qt Documents is always the first place to go when encountering a problem.

Comment: Thankx for your reply ..
@oggmonster - i have been through that link , which u have provided here .. But what i want to know is how to create a folder using one dialogbox(like we use for  creating one file by using QFiledialog::getsaveFilename())

Comment: You need to specify your question in more detail. But what I think you need to do is use the QDir::mkpath("your file path") in response to some user action. You haven't described what user action that is

Comment: @oggmonster here the user action is to create one folder .
There is one button in my project , so when the user click that button at that time one dialog box should open where the user may allow to give the folder name , through that dialog box the user allow to select the location , like whether he wants to create the folder in desktop or c drive or d drive . if the folder is already present in that specific location then it will ask for replacement to the user , if the user press yes then it will replace that folder or else the folder is not getting replaced .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A usual GUI approach to this would be to use `QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(QWidget* parent, const QString& caption, const QString& dir, Options options)` to present a directory selection dialog to the user.  Have the output of the selection displayed a in `QLineEdit`, so if the user wants to create a new subdirectory they can append new folder names.

Then as the comments to your question state, use `QDir` to determine if the directory is existing or not - and make it if it isn't.