# How to create dir if needed from filename of non-existing file in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, path, dir

I wish my app to write a file in a specified location, and therefore create the appropriate directory if needed.
The create dir operation isn't a problem for me, but I need the dir path.
I could extract if from the file path, but maybe is there a quick/concise/convenient way of doing the full operation?

I repeat, I'm not searching the basic makedir function, but one which would take the filename of a possibly non-existing file, or a simple qt function to extract the dir path string from the file path string, so I dont' have to write a func for such a basic task.

Comment: Have you searched on google? see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2241818/3062311)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if a folder exists (and creating folders) in Qt, C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241808/checking-if-a-folder-exists-and-creating-folders-in-qt-c)

Comment: I'd suggest the `mkpath()` as suggested in the [secondmost upvoted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11517874/3399252)

Comment: Thanks, I searched google and docs, but have you really read my question?

Comment: So, do you have the full filename, from which you want to extract only the dir path without the file name?

Comment: yes, I have the full filename, something like "c:\toto\photo.jpg", or "/home/toto/photo.jpg", and I 'd like the dir to exist before I try to write my file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
const QString filePath = "C:/foo/bar/file.ini";
QDir().mkpath(QFileInfo(filePath).absolutePath());
```

This code will automatically create the path to the specified (nonexistent) file.

---

> [`QFileInfo::absolutePath()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html#absolutePath) extracts the absolute path to the specified file.
>
> [`QDir::mkpath()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#mkpath) creates the previously extracted path.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a full path to the file and need to extract the folder path, you can do it this way:

```
QFile file(full_path_to_the_file);
QFileInfo info(file);
QString directoryPath = info.absolutePath();
//now you can check if the dir exists:
if(QDir(directoryPath).exists())
    //do stuff
```

Depending on what *exactly* you need, you may prefer to use `QFileInfo::canonicalPath()` instead of `absolutePath`

Alternatively, you may also use `QFileInfo::absoluteDir`:

```
QFile file(full_path_to_the_file);
QFileInfo info(file);
if(info.absoluteDir().exists())
    //do stuff
```

Comment: Thanks, I finally use QFileInfo(QFile(path)).absolutePath() to get the dir path and create it if needed. As this is a very current situation, I hoped there would be a dedicated function for this, but this remains light enough.

Comment: Just for information: Trying with canonicalPath() failed for me (but absolutePath() is fine)