# Qt can't find created directory

Tags: c++, qt

So I've created a folder using the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241808/checking-if-a-folder-exists-and-creating-folders-in-qt-c) and I'm sort of stuck.
I create the directory and check if it exists

```
QDir().mkdir(path);

if(QDir(path).exists()) {
    std::cout<<"created!\n";
}
else {
    std::cout<<"not created!\n";
}
```

console outputs that the directory is created but I can't find it.
It's not in the project folder.
I also tried to search for it in Finder.

Comment: Can you please provide the value of the `path` variable, log output and the folder where you are looking for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Qt5.

The default constructor for [`QDir(const QString& path = QString())`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#QDir-1) creates instance of the `QDir` pointing to the current working directory.  Check the [`QDir::current()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#current) static method.

The [`QDir::mkdir(const QString& dirName)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#mkdir) creates the sub directory in the current the instance points to. The return value is true if the directory was successfully created.

So for your specific case the directory described in `path` will be created in current working directory of the program. For debugging purposes you can log [`QDir(path).absolutePath()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#absolutePath).

Normally while debugging in XCode it sets the current working directory to something like "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/-ddettossvnbbvaarrlgkfotjkeew/Build/Products/" with the "ddettossvnbbvaarrlgkfotjkeew" being generated for the target, project and some other parameters.

If the problem persists please add more data to your question.

Comment: Sry. I'm an idiot. The folder was in the qt app. So I went to show Package Contents and the folder was there